# Angular UI-Bootstrap Pagination

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have my ng-repeat template as;

`ng-repeat="student in students| filter:searchText | filter: paginate  "`

while in the controller I have;

```
$scope.currentPage = 1; 
$scope.itemsPerPage = 20;  
$scope.paginate = function (value) {  
    var begin, end, index;  
    begin = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage;  
    end = begin + $scope.itemsPerPage;  
    index = $scope.students.indexOf(value);  
    return (begin <= index && index < end);  
};
```

The pagination is working but when I filter by seachText the filtered results stay in their old paginated pages.

How can I make the filtered results come to the first page.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
var sap=angular.module('doApp',['ui.bootstrap']);
sap.filter('startFrom',function(){ 
    return function(input,start){
        if(input){
            start =+start;
            return input.slice(start);
        }
        return [];
        }
});
```

and make this change to ng-repeat..

```
<tr ng-repeat="student in filtered=(students | filter:serachText) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit">
```

Where entrylimit could be

```
 $scope.entryLimit=5;
```

just add this entrylimit in your paginate function.
hope this will help..